# Ignore field in select Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eager-loading

Consider these models:

**Flight Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable =
  [
      'userID'
  ];    

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'userID');
  }
}
```

**User Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable =
  [
      'userID', 'username', 'address'
  ];    
}
```

I want to skip a column when I'm trying to use eager loading. I just want to know if something like IGNORE_FIELD FUNCTION exists, so I can do something like this:

```
$flightUser = Flight::with(['user', function ($q)
{
    $q->ignoreField('user.address');
}])
```

I know I could push the address field into the hidden array inside the **User Model**,

```
protected $hidden = ['address'];
```

or do the `$q->select('fields')` and not including the address field, but my real doubt is whether laravel has a function like the one I typed above.

**NOTE**

I know one field isn't that big of a deal. But my question is a simplified version of my real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you're getting at.  You could change the eloquent relation so that it never loads that field.

```
class Flight extends Model {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'userID')
            ->select(['userID', 'username']);
    }

}
```

So that relation will never load anything besides the userID and username.  If you wanted to differentiate, you could even call the full one `user()` and the limited one `userName()`.

```
class Flight extends Model {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'userID');
    }

    public function userName()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'userID')
            ->select(['userID', 'username']);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, that would do the trick. But I'm still wondering whether Laravel thas such function. I guess not

Comment: No, not to my knowledge.  I've looked for a veritable `removeSelect()` before, but aside from my solution, or removing them manually with collection methods, there is no such function built into laravel.  Honestly if it's that important, you may just be better off not using an eloquent relationship and just writing two queries.